# How can I preview HTML documents from the command line?

Tags: command-line, html

I use `catdoc` to preview Word documents from the command line. Is there something similar for HTML?

In other words I would like to do `cathtml Webpage.html | less` and get more or less a `man` page look output.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `html2text` to look into an HTML document from command line.

```
sudo apt-get install html2text
html2text Webpage.html | less
```

but not exactly a look similar to man pages, it depends on the html input, of course.

Answer (score 38):

One solution is to use `lynx -dump`, as in

```
lynx -dump file.html
```

or

```
echo "<div>this is a div</div>" | lynx -dump -stdin
```

---

### Better:

Use `w3m -dump`, it respects the page layout. It is awesome.

```
sudo aptitude install w3m
w3m -dump file.html
echo "<div>x</div>" | w3m -dump -T text/html
```

You can set the number of columns of the terminal for getting the better layout, for example, if you are using a full-window terminal, 200 can be a good try:

```
w3m -dump -cols 200 file.html
```

Answer (score 16):

You could use `w3m` which should already installed - if however it isn't

```
sudo apt-get install w3m
```

An example command syntax:

```
w3m -dump askubuntu.com | less
```

It can be used with both URL's as well as file-based html files

```
w3m -dump index.html | less
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are these so-called text html browsers, of which I have successfully tested [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29) and [ELinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks). Of which ELinks has become my favorite.

Anyway, they are different than a "web page previewer" as you suggest in your question. They are more like active real-time browsers, which carry lots of useful features for easy web browsing and of course, you can also use it for local/remote web pages preview.

Information about Lynx is in the Wikipedia and can be reached [clicking here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29). The information related to the ELinks is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks).

My ELinks screenshot for you to see ELinks in action:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Looks very good indeed.

Comment: Ah - so obvious! After I wrote this question I used `w3m`, that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a use of [`html2text`](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/) and [`mdless`](https://github.com/ttscoff/mdless).

```
html2text Webpage.html | mdless
```

Alternativly plus [`curl`](https://curl.se/) to download the file first

```
curl https://askubuntu.com | html2text | mdless
```

The curl does download the file in the `stdin` of `html2text`. This gives `mdless` the markdown which will be shown like a pager.

It is not the same as the `man` pages. And you can't click on links like on real browser, for that use [`w3m`](https://askubuntu.com/a/58419/1167734) or [`elinks`](https://askubuntu.com/a/58424/1167734)